# How to get the data from sqlite - Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a little problem with getting the elements in my sqlite database in android.My database looks like this :

```
id  /   serverName  /  objectId  /  objectOid  /  ....//objectId is actually userId-which I need to compare
```

I'm receiving an data from the server and I need to check the id of user from the server and local user id from the database.I have this piece of code :

```
public static Integer lUserIdByServerUserId(int serverUserId, String serverName){
    return localUserIdByServerUserId( serverUserId,  serverName);

}

private static Integer localUserIdByServerUserId(int serverUserId, String serverName){
    DataBaseHelper dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, "ops_sys_tpl.sqlite",null,1);
    String query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE objectId = "+serverUserId+" AND serverName = '"+serverName+"' LIMIT 1";
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    cursor = dbHelper.executeSQLQuery(query);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        result.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("objectId")));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    Log.i("result ","Result : "+result.toString());
    Log.i("CURSOR ","Cursor Position : "+cursor.getPosition());
    Integer uuid = Integer.parseInt(result.get(cursor.getColumnIndex("objectId")));
    Log.w("localUSerByIdServerUserId","LocalUserByIdServerUserId result : "+uuid);
    cursor.close();
    return uuid;
}
```

I am trying to check all the entries in database and if there is a match return it.I'm calling this method like this :

```
            uuId = rpc.lUserIdByServerUserId(userId,newServerName);
```

and i get this exception at this line :  `Integer uuid = Integer.parseInt(result.get(cursor.getColumnIndex("objectId")));`

```
  09-20 16:55:47.647: WARN/System.err(31031): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
09-20 16:55:47.647: WARN/System.err(31031):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
09-20 16:55:47.647: WARN/System.err(31031):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
09-20 16:55:47.647: WARN/System.err(31031):     at com.stampii.stampii.comm.rpc.RPCCommunicator.localUserIdByServerUserId(RPCCommunicator.java:1083)
09-20 16:55:47.647: WARN/System.err(31031):     at com.stampii.stampii.comm.rpc.RPCCommunicator.lUserIdByServerUserId(RPCCommunicator.java:1066)
09-20 16:55:47.657: WARN/System.err(31031):     at com.stampii.stampii.comm.rpc.InfoStartRPCPacket.executeBefore(InfoStartRPCPacket.java:176)
09-20 16:55:47.657: WARN/System.err(31031):     at com.stampii.stampii.user.UserLogin$2$1.run(UserLogin.java:212)
09-20 16:55:47.657: WARN/System.err(31031):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1102)
09-20 16:55:47.657: WARN/ERROR(31031):  Error  - java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

And actually I have only one test entry in my database which is the same as the userID return from server.

Any ideas where is my mistake and how to fix that?

Comment: what line is (RPCCommunicator.java:1083)? Mark the lines of code please.

Comment: sorry forget to mention it. I just update my question with the correct line which is  :  Integer uuid = Integer.parseInt(result.get(cursor.getColumnIndex("objectId")));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was due to cursor's position

Try this code for position the cursor to start point.

```
 if (mNotesCursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do {
         result.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("objectId")));
      } while (mNotesCursor.moveToNext());
 }
```

Comment: In this line :  Integer uuid = Integer.parseInt(result.get(cursor.getColumnIndex("objectId")));

Comment: @Bombastic Put that line inside the do loop and try.My guess is that after it get all values the cursor comes to end position. and now if you try to get value it throws exception

Comment: If i put the uuId in the loop it returns null as a result,and I've already checked my database file from emulator that I have at least one record.

Comment: Actually I fix that! Thanks a lot!!!Just a little question, how can I put all the rows in ArrayList or HashMap? Not only objectId.

Comment: I just pull it out the loop and it worked.About the other question...I mean how can I get the whole rows in ArrayList :  result.add(cursor.getString("users")); or something like that...

Comment: @Bombastic yes right but this line should be inside the loop.